# Opera 10 eating CPU on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, opera

I've been used Opera for many years (since Opera 7, the ad-supported one).

Now I'm on big trouble: since something like 2 snapshots before the first RC, it's eating my CPU and rendering my computer somewhat slow, and itself gets totally unusable, SO MUCH slow.

I don't have any idea of how start fixing it... I'm updating it on every new release (all the RCs, the stable, the new snapshots...), and all of then keep eating my CPU.

I can't get by working with Firefox. I'm a web developer and I got used to work with Opera and just use Firefox for testing.

I have:

- never used any widgets;
- already tried closing all the ten tabs; no success at all;
- already tried to disable plugins, Java, JS, everything; no success also.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera 10 final works quite well on my Ubuntu 9.04 systems. Have you tried starting over, moving away your ~/.opera directory? You should be able to keep your bookmarks and wand passwords eventually, but for a first test, I'd simply move the complete directory (rename it) and see if that solves and problems.

Comment: It worked! o.O I'll try to move on the folders slowly and see what happens... Do you have any hint?

Comment: I migrated everything except the cache folders. Great =D +1 for you

Comment: So your cache was somehow borked? That would have been my last hint ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Clearing cache helped me too. 
I just went into Opera 10 tools->delete private data and selected 'cache'
The CPU usage immediately dropped to normal.

Comment: it's basically what I did.... but in a more drastic way. xD